# How to make windows computer detectable with AirPlay?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, mac, multiple-monitors

How can I make so when I click the AirPlay button on my mac it detects my windows computer so that I can mirror my screen to it (or extend my screen to it). Is there a program for this that is free?

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/where-to-get-airplay-for-windows-2000736

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can't link or connect a samsung with an iphone so I guess it s  going be the same for  an OS X machine and a  Windows machine  but I may be wrong